# Attribute Error when using QEasingCurve in PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6

I am trying to set easing curve for controlling animation of a simple frame

```
    self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b'minimumWidth')
    self.animation.setDuration(100)
    self.animation.setStartValue(150)
    self.animation.setEndValue(300)
    self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuad)
    self.animation.start()
```

But I get this error:

AttributeError: type object 'QEasingCurve' has no attribute 'InOutQuad'

I tried other curve options Linear, InQuad, OutQuad, all gives same error,
Please Help.

Comment: PyQt6 has changed the way flags/enums are accessible. In your case, it should be `QtCore.QEasingCurve.Type.InOutQuad`.

Comment: Thanks once again Maurizio for pointing out the changes, problem solved, You did help me once before with another question too!